# How to get value from custom drop down field of system config in magento 2

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

I need the value of selected value from system config file.

Below is my code example.

**system.xml** file

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Select Product Tab</label>
     <source_model>Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Products</source_model>                 
</field>
```

**Model** file

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Products implements ArrayInterface
{

    /*
     * Option getter
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    /*
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $valList = [
            '1' => 'A',
            '2' => 'B',
            '3' => 'C',
            '4' => 'D'

        ];
        return $valList;
    }
}
```

I need selected value in block or template file

Comment: have you got answer? need your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in your block.

```
protected $scopeConfig;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ....
}
```

Then create the method `getStoreValue()`

```
public function getStoreValue()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/store_information/name',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

and call in your template `echo $this->getStoreValue()`

Answer (score 0):

**system.xml**

```
        <field id="super_admin"
               translate="label"
               type="select"
               sortOrder="10"
               showInDefault="1"
               showInWebsite="1"
               showInStore="1">
            <label>Select Admin</label>
            <source_model>VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\AdminUserList</source_model>
          <validate>required-entry</validate>
        </field>
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source**

**AdminUserList.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source;

use Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\CollectionFactory as UserCollectionFactory;

class AdminUserList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $_userFactory;

    public function __construct(
        UserCollectionFactory $userFactory
    ) {
        $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
    }
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $adminUsers = $this->_userFactory->create();
        $options = [];
        foreach ($adminUsers as $adminUser) {
            $options[$adminUser->getId()] = $adminUser->getUsername();
        }
        return $options;
    }
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Helper**

**Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    const ADMIN_USER_NAME = 'custom_module/general/super_admin'; // sectionName/GroupName/FieldName from system.xml

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function setStoreScope()
    {
        return ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    }
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::ADMIN_USER_NAME, $this->setStoreScope());
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score -1):

You can use **ScopeConfigInterface** class to get value

```
<?php 

protected $_storeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ---
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ) {
        $this->_storeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        echo $this->_storeConfig->getValue('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');die;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Comment: this code is not working...